# SyntaxError at /images/new syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_DEND, expecting ')'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml, erb

I am new to haml and this is the first time I am using it. I have a form in Haml to create tags. I am getting a

```
Syntax error: unexpected tString_DEND expecting ')'.
unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
haml_temp =  f.content_tag :div, "", class: "container_button" do
```

The line generating the error are:

```
= f.text_area :tag_list, label: "Tags (optional)", help: raw("All tags .<br>We do this to ensure..."), input_html:{data:{placeholder: "Enter tags", saved: f.object.tags.map{|t|{id: t.name, name:t.name}}.to_json}, url: autocomplete_tags_path}, class: 'tagselect'}
```

Can you please help ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `f.textarea` line you posted has an extra `}` at the end. Here is the code without the extraneous `}`

```
= f.text_area :tag_list, label: "Tags (optional)", help: raw("All tags .<br>We do this to ensure..."), input_html:{data:{placeholder: "Enter tags", saved: f.object.tags.map{|t|{id: t.name, name:t.name}}.to_json}, url: autocomplete_tags_path}, class: 'tagselect'
```